# Conjecture: Every prime number is the difference between a prime number and a power of $2$

Tags: prime-numbers, conjectures

Conjecture:

> $\forall p\in\mathbb P\exists q\in\mathbb P\exists n\in \mathbb N: q-p=2^n$

Verified for the 100 first primes.

Comment: Please try to reach more streamlined titles in your future questions, taking as example the modified version of the present title.

Comment: @Did, do you mean that the present title is bad or good? Are you refering to other of my titles? It's difficult to understand what you're aiming at.

Comment: Seriously? What I wrote explicitely is that the former title was bad, that I modified it, and that you could try to imitate the current title for your future questions on the site. Clearer now?

Comment: @Did. Now everything is clear. Thanks for the tip! I didn't notice that also you edited the title.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49786/form-of-primesprime-plus-a-power-of-2) discusses the existence/infinitude of primes $p$ that can be written in the form $$p = q \pm 2^n$$ where $q$ is a prime and $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

In particular for $p = q - 2^n$, Gjergji Zaimi mentions in a comment to his asnwer that $$p = 47,867,742,232,066,880,047,611,079$$ is a counterexample.