# Prime=prime + power of 2 infinitely often?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

I just experimented with some small primes and obtained $7=2^2+3$ and $13=2^3+5$ and $17=2^2+13$ and $23=2^4+7$.

All these primes are sum of a prime and a power of $2$.

So it naturally led me to conjecture:

> There is an infinite number of primes $p$ so that $p=2^k+q$, where $q$ is another prime and $k \in \mathbb N$

You can see that it is also allowed that $k=1$ so, if there were an infinite number of twin primes (or any pairs of primes that differ by some fixed $2^k$) then this conjecture would be trivially true.

But, this is far weaker conjecture because it allows all powers of $2$ at once.

Is this known?

Comment: Basing conjectures on experiments up to $p=23$ is a very poor idea...if you want to search you need to go a lot deeper.  That said, presumably this is true (as, presumably, there are infinitely many twin primes) but it seems unlikely that it can be proven with current methods.

Comment: @lulu This could be within reach.

Comment: There are really many such questions, e.g., see also [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259625/on-primes-of-the-form-2n-k?noredirect=1&lq=1), and the related ones at the right margin. This is not a new question.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I know, but I am a conjecturer.

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen it is easy to be a conjecturer but generally the  mathematicians having made the greatest accomplishments in terms of actually completing important & difficult proofs, come up with interesting conjectures because thanks to their great skill and deep understanding of their field, they are able to appreciate what conjectures are actually important. Many famous conjectures have known, far-reaching consequences if true. Yours here is interesting but would be more so if accompanied by a clear understanding of what its implications would be.

Comment: @RobertFrost Nice observation and explanation. Thank you.

Comment: What is the smallest odd prime that **cannot** be written as a sum of a prime and a power of two? (if there is one!)

Comment: Seems to be 127. OEIS confirms my program: https://oeis.org/A065381

Comment: @yper-trollᵀᴹ Excellent find. Although there are infinitely many such numbers, it looks like Antoine's conjecture is indeed true after all.

Comment: FYI, this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865207/conjecture-every-prime-number-is-the-difference-between-a-prime-number-and-a-po/1865214) asks a closely related one of if each prime $p$ has at least one prime $q$ & natural number $n$ with $p = q \pm 2^n$. An answer links to an MO question & says $p=47,867,742,232,066,880,047,611,079$ is a counterexample. This seems to come from a 1975 paper given at [Not Every Number is the Sum or Difference of Two Prime Powers](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1975-29-129/S0025-5718-1975-0376583-0/S0025-5718-1975-0376583-0.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

There is a conjecture that for every even positive integer $d$, there are infinite many pairs of primes $p,q$ with $p+d=q$. This implies this conjecture. In fact, for every power of $2$, we would only need one such pair.

Another heuristic for the conjecture. For every prime power $2^k$, there are infinite many odd numbers $o$, such that $2^k+o$ is prime. It seems very likely that there is at least one prime number (probably even infinite many prime numbers) among those odd numbers.

Nevertheless, I am sceptical about a proof of this conjecture, although at first glance, it does not appear to be too difficult.